# Tensorflow - Create an operation conditionally on one of its placeholder value

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have an operation `multiply_square` that multiplies the squared value of two placeholders `x`and `y`

```
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.float32)
multiply_square = tf.square(x) * tf.square(y)
```

I want to define this operation *conditionally* on some particular realization of `y`. For instance I want to create the operation `square`,  imposing `y=1` by doing something like the following:

```
square = multiply_square(y=1)  #for square, y is a constant=1
```

which now only depends on `x` (and returns the square of `x`). I'd then be able to run the following command:

```
xvals = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
with tf.Session as session:
    session.run(square, feed_dict{x: xvals})  #returns [1.0, 4.0, 9.0]
```

without Tensorflow complaining that I haven't specified a value for `y`.

I know this is easily achievable when `x` and `y` are `tf.Variable` (using `tf.assign`). Is there anyway to do that with placeholders (and without using eager execution)?
Also, I would like for the solution to be independent of how the graph is build as I want to implement such a method in some already existing code.

The motivation behind this toy example is the following. I want to design a scalar loss that writes like:

```
loss(x,y) = f(x,y) + g(x,y=z)
```

where both `f` and `g` are functions of `x` and `y` but `g` is partially evaluated at `y=z`. Now I want to evaluate or optimize `loss` while feeding it  some values for its placeholders `x` and `y` while having `y` still evaluated to `z` in the second part of the loss.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: Conditionally build your graph

I think there are 2 ways you can do this: conditionally build your graph or use [tf.placeholder_with_default](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default). I think the former is easier and more in line with what you mentioned your constraints to be.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.reset_default_graph()

# Conditionally build your graph in python: if x_val or y_val is provided,
# use that value instead of expecting it to be fed.


def build_graph(x_val=None, y_val=None):
  # Conditionally build a constant or a placeholder for x.
  if x_val:
    x = tf.constant(x_val, dtype=tf.float32)
  else:
    x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.float32)

  # Conditionally build a constant or a placeholder for y.
  if y_val:
    y = tf.constant(y_val, dtype=tf.float32)
  else:
    y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.float32)

  multiply_square = tf.square(x) * tf.square(y)
  return x, y, multiply_square


x, y, square = build_graph(y_val=1)  # for square, y is a constant=1
xvals = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])

with tf.Session() as session:
  square_out = session.run(square, feed_dict={x: xvals})
  print(square_out)
```

## Solution 2: Feed in a "broadcasted" constant

The way to "assign" to a placeholder is to feed the value. If you don't want to change the graph, you can just change the fed value for y to be the same for every x.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# v2, feed a constant to the placeholder

def build_graph():
  x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.float32)
  y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.float32)
  multiply_square = tf.square(x) * tf.square(y)
  return x, y, multiply_square


def get_y_from_constant(y_constant, x_vals):
  # Get an np array with the same shape and type as x_vals, full of y_constant
  yvals = np.full_like(x_vals, y_constant, dtype=x_vals.dtype)
  return yvals


tf.reset_default_graph()
x, y, square = build_graph()

with tf.Session() as session:
  xvals = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
  yvals = get_y_from_constant(1, xvals) # We want y to be 1 for all x_vals
  x_out, y_out, square_out = session.run(
      [x, y, square],
      feed_dict={x: xvals, y: yvals})
  print(x_out)       # x:       [1. 2. 3.]
  print(y_out)       # y:       [1. 1. 1.]
  print(square_out)  # square:  [1. 4. 9.]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I edited my question to precise that I actually don't want to change how my graph is built. In the application I am concerned with, the graph already exists and I can't change its construction (_i.e_ conditional or not). Also, I can't really use `tf.placeholders_with_default` if for instance I want to create _several_ conditional operations (i.e with the notations of my post, `square_1 = multiply_square(y=1)` and `square_2 = multiply_square(y=2)`

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to feed the constant value for y? The way to "assign" to a placeholder is to feed the value. If you don't want to change the graph, you can just change the fed value for y to be the same for every x. I've added a second solution to my answer above

Comment: There is one. What I want in the end is to have a loss of the form `loss(x,y)= f(x,y) + g(x,y=z)` where `g` is a function of `x,y` but partially evaluated at `y=z`. Now when I want to evaluate or optimize `loss`, I want to feed the placeholders `x` and `y` to their actual values, but still with `g` taking `y=z`. My post is probably unclear about that, I edited it to hopefully make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: You are asking for something to have 2 values at the same time which is not possible. A couple of solutions:

One way is to add additional `assign` ops (and maybe a `placeholder` as well if you want for easily feeding it) to your graph. You can dynamically find all the places in `g` where `y` is used and add some `assign` ops to assign `z` to all variables that took the value from placeholder `y`.

Another way would be to create two copies of your graph and feed `x, y` to `f` and `x,y=z` to `g`, calculate a combined loss and apply the gradients yourself to the respective sub-graphs

Comment: Yes, `assign` is nice way to do it when `x` and `y` are Variables. In the end, I recoded my graph to create two subgraphs with shared variable, and different input tensor, and obtained the desired result. Thanks!